# How to filter an array of objects based on the first character of a property in the array of object?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to filter through an array of objects based on the first number of a property and I can;t get it to work properly.

What I should have returning from the filter is the objects RowNumber has a starting row number of 1, and I need to use the filter method. I can probably use a for loop and get the objects that I am looking to have returned, but would rather use the filter method as its cleaner.

```js
(function() {
  const ds = [{
      ID: 1,
      RowNumber: "1"
    },
    {
      ID: 2,
      RowNumber: "1.01"
    },
    {
      ID: 3,
      RowNumber: "1.02"
    },
    {
      ID: 4,
      RowNumber: "1.03"
    },
    {
      ID: 5,
      RowNumber: "2.01"
    }
  ];

  const gridDs = [{
      ID: 1,
      RowNumber: "1",
      Name: "Box 1"
    },
    {
      ID: 2,
      RowNumber: "1.01",
      Name: "Box 2"
    },
    {
      ID: 3,
      RowNumber: "1.02",
      Name: "Box 3"
    },
    {
      ID: 4,
      RowNumber: "1.03",
      Name: "Box 4"
    },
    {
      ID: 5,
      RowNumber: "",
      Name: ""
    },
    {
      ID: 6,
      RowNumber: "2",
      Name: ""
    },
    {
      ID: 7,
      RowNumber: "2.01",
      Name: "Box 7"
    },
    {
      ID: 8,
      RowNumber: "2.02",
      Name: "Box 8"
    },
    {
      ID: 9,
      RowNumber: "3",
      Name: "Box 9"
    },
  ];
  const firstItem = ds[0];
  const itemSplit = firstItem.RowNumber.split(".");
  const foundItems = gridDs.filter(f => f.RowNumber === firstItem.RowNumber && f.RowNumber.split(".")[0] === parseInt(itemSplit));

  console.log(foundItems);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`itemSplit` is an array. You need to get the first element of it, and parse it to an integers.

In the `filter()` call, you shouldn't check `f.RowNumber === firstItem.RowNumber` since you only care about the part before `.` in `f.rowNumber`. Parse the first part of this, and compare it with the number you're searching for.

```js
(function() {
  const ds = [{
      ID: 1,
      RowNumber: "1"
    },
    {
      ID: 2,
      RowNumber: "1.01"
    },
    {
      ID: 3,
      RowNumber: "1.02"
    },
    {
      ID: 4,
      RowNumber: "1.03"
    },
    {
      ID: 5,
      RowNumber: "2.01"
    }
  ];

  const gridDs = [{
      ID: 1,
      RowNumber: "1",
      Name: "Box 1"
    },
    {
      ID: 2,
      RowNumber: "1.01",
      Name: "Box 2"
    },
    {
      ID: 3,
      RowNumber: "1.02",
      Name: "Box 3"
    },
    {
      ID: 4,
      RowNumber: "1.03",
      Name: "Box 4"
    },
    {
      ID: 5,
      RowNumber: "",
      Name: ""
    },
    {
      ID: 6,
      RowNumber: "2",
      Name: ""
    },
    {
      ID: 7,
      RowNumber: "2.01",
      Name: "Box 7"
    },
    {
      ID: 8,
      RowNumber: "2.02",
      Name: "Box 8"
    },
    {
      ID: 9,
      RowNumber: "3",
      Name: "Box 9"
    },
  ];
  const firstItem = ds[0];
  const searchNumber = parseInt(firstItem.RowNumber.split(".")[0]);
  const foundItems = gridDs.filter(f => parseInt(f.RowNumber.split(".")[0]) === searchNumber);

  console.log(foundItems);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That did the trick, and thank you for the explanation. I'll accept as soon as I am able too.

Comment: I applied your solution and ran into an issue on the real data, some of those objects may not have an ItemRowNumber property, how do I deal with that in this current situation?

Comment: Should those be included or excluded?

Comment: If the object has no RowNumber then that object should be skipped, what I did was took the array of objects and did a filter on those where RowNumber != null and used that in instead of doing a filter on gridDs

Comment: `f => f.rowNumber && ...`